# Sql insert data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a doubt. i need the syntax  for SQL SERVER – how to **Insert Data From One Table to Another Table?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1,...)
SELECT col1,...
FROM table1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*different records but have same thought*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e81c/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert INTO Table1 (UserName) (Select UName From Table2 b Where Table1.EID = b.EID)
```

But Showing Message:

`The multi-part identifier "Table1.EID" could not be bound.`